# wp get_post of custom post type and images

Tags: wordpress

am trying to get 10 post of a custom post type

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'post_type' => 'mycustomposttype'  );

    $myposts = get_posts( $args ); 


    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );    

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) 
        {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); 


            //my template here  
        }

    endforeach;
```

The if statement

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
```

returns false but all of my custom post have image

Now if i change the 'numberposts' => 10 to 'numberposts' => 100
i get the images of the posts

What am i missing here

Comment: what happens if you change `numberposts` to `posts_per_page`?

Comment: posts_per_page has the same problem

Comment: @M.Doye `numberposts` is changed to `posts_per_page` in `get_posts()` before beign passed to `WP_Query`.

Comment: There is just nothing in your code that would suggest why your code would fail, except maybe for the missing `wp_reset_postdata();` after `endforeach`. Run the same query with `WP_Query` (*remember to switch to `posts_per_page`*) and see if you get the same result